# Why is my C++ code wrong to calculate the maximum and minimum of integers?

Tags: c++

I am learning the C++ programming language and I am a beginner. I had to write a code so that a user inputs a series of integers and whenever he enters -99, that should signal the end of the series and then my program needs to find the smallest and largest integers. I initially came up with this solution

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int k=0, number, maximum, minimum;
    do
    {
        cout<<"Enter an integer: ";
        cin>>number;
        if (number==-99)
        {
            break;
        }
        if (k==0)
        {
            maximum=number;
            minimum=number;
        }
        if (number>maximum)
        {
            maximum=number;
        }
        if (number<minimum)
        {
            minimum=number;
        }
        k++;
    }
    while(number!=-99);
    cout<<"The smallest entered integer is "
    <<minimum
    <<" and the largest entered integer is "
    <<maximum
    <<endl;
    return(0);
}
```

and sent it to my lecturer and asked if there is a cleaner way of doing this but he did not reply. Next, I changed this program to find the maximum and minimum using the formulas max(x,y)=(x+y+abs(y-x))/2 and min(x,y)=(x+y-abs(y-x))/2 instead using comparisons.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int k=0, number, maximum, minimum;
    do
    {
        cout<<"Enter an integer: ";
        cin>>number;
        if (number==-99)
        {
            break;
        }
        if (k==0)
        {
            maximum=number;
            minimum=number;
        }
        maximum=(maximum+number+abs(number-maximum))/2;
        minimum=(minimum+number-abs(number-minimum))/2;
        k++;
    }
    while(number!=-99);
    cout<<"The smallest entered integer is "
    <<minimum
    <<" and the largest entered integer is "
    <<maximum
    <<endl;
    return(0);
}
```

but this time my lecturer replied and the only thing he said was that it is wrong. I have tested both of my codes few times and they show me the correct result so I have no clue what my lecturer meant by saying it is wrong. Could someone please let me know why any of the two codes above is wrong and why?

Comment: What exactly was wrong with the first on? It looked okay to me.

Comment: Also, not really sure what you're trying to do with the second one.

Comment: @Chipster: Thanks for your comment. In the second one, I am trying to solve the same problem as the first one but instead using comparisons to find the maximum and minimum, I find them by using math formulas max(x,y)=(x+y+abs(y-x))/2 and min(x,y)=(x+y-abs(y-x))/2. This can be found in exercise 13 on page 16 of Spivak Calculus (fourth edition).

Comment: @Vafa *if there is a cleaner way of doing this but he did not reply* -- [I can reply](https://www.ideone.com/Y8G2z3).  Second, why are you resorting to math formulas to get the minimum and maximum of a set of integers?  All that will do is confuse fellow programmers as to what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Hmm. Again, I say it looks okay to me. Any idea what exactly is wrong with it? Is there something else in the assignment you missed?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie That doesn't halt when the next integer is -99.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thanks for your comment. I was just trying to test different things as I am learning that is why I resorted to math formulas. I guess that maybe my lecturer was also confused and he did not understand the logic of my program.

Comment: I'd use `minimum = std::min(minimum, number);` etc. instead of `if`'s, and check to make sure reading an int succeeded instead of assuming it does.

Comment: Now would be a good time to invest in learning to use a debugger.  The debugger will let you execute statement by statement.

Comment: Both are incorrect because when the first entry is -99, minimum and maximum are uninitialized and therefore the result is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Both of your programs work fine. If you'd like it be cleaner than you can do the following:

- Check if the input succeeded before using `number`. You can do this by putting the input operation in a `while` loop.
- Just use the `max` and `min` functions found in `<cmath>`.

This will be your program:

```c++
int main() {
  int number = -100, maximum = -99, minimum = 99;
  while (cin >> number && number != -99) {
    maximum = max(maximum, number);
    minimum = min(minimum, number);
  }
  if (number == -99) {
    cout << "The smallest entered integer is "     << minimum
         << " and the largest entered integer is " << maximum << endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: Also incorrect when the sequence of numbers before -99 has zero occurrences above -99 or  zero occurrences of numbers under 99 (e.g. "-99" or "-200 -100 -99" or "100 200 -99"

Comment: @ComeRaczy You're right about the null input part but for the second part I figure -99 has to be the lower bound of the input (and so I made +99 the upper bound). If the OP wants to change this he can use `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX` respectively.

Comment: INT_MIN and INT_MAX would work (even though it’s a C answer) but this doesn’t change the fact that without checking for out of bound values 99 and -99 will lead to incorrect answers (that’s obviously the second input the lecturer will try)

Comment: @ComeRaczy Yes but like I said I'm assuming the input *will* be a number between -99 and 99.

Comment: The second program doesn't work fine.  It can allow undefined behavior (due to signed integer overflow)

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to correct the problem. One is to check for the value of k in your initial example to verify that a value was actually entered and that minimum and maximum are initialized.

A slightly different approach that might impress your lecturer is to initialize minimum and maximum to values that will lead to a correct result. std::numeric_limits provides the minimum and maximum values for integers. Using this you could implement something along these lines:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    int number;
    int maximum = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
    int minimum = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
    while ((std::cin >> number) && (number != -99))
    {
        maximum = std::max(maximum, number);
        minimum = std::min(minimum, number);
    }
    if (std::cin)
    {
        if ((maximum != std::numeric_limits<int>::min()) || (minimum != std::numeric_limits<int>::max()))
        {
            std::cout << "maximum = " << maximum << std::endl;
            std::cout << "minimum = " << minimum << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "No number entered" << std::endl;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Errorr reading the number" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The formulas used in your second code snippet are mathematically correct, but have drawbacks if used in computer programming where **variables have limited range**.

The first code snippet works across the entire representable set of integers (except `-99` for obvious reasons).

The second code snippet will not work for inputs whose absolute value is greater than `INT_MIN / -2`, because the computations will overflow.

Don't feel bad, this bug is not at all obvious and a lot of programmers have overlooked it.  For a related example, see:

- [Extra, Extra - Read All About It: Nearly All Binary Searches and Mergesorts are Broken](https://ai.googleblog.com/2006/06/extra-extra-read-all-about-it-nearly.html)

Unfortunately, if you have this kind of bug in code processing untrusted input, your range checking could fail and lead to a security vulnerability.  So don't go ignoring it just because "I never expect inputs that large".

Answer (score -1):

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cmath>
    using namespace std;
    int main()
    {
        int number, maximum=0, minimum=0;
        bool isDirty = false;
        do
        {
            cout<<"Enter an integer: ";
            cin>>number;
            if(number!=-99){
               if(isDirty==false) {
                 isDirty = true;
                 minimum = maximum =number;
               } else {
                  if (number < minimum) { 
                    minimum = number;
                   } 
                   if (number > maximum){ 
                     maximum = number;
                   }

                 } 
            }
        }
        while(number!=-99);

        cout<<"The smallest entered integer is "
        <<minimum
        <<" and the largest entered integer is "
        <<maximum
        <<endl;
        return(0);
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't work. If the users only inputs positive numbers, the condition (number < minimum will never be true and minimum will stay at 0. Same with negative numbers only.

Comment: Thank you my friends. I hope it is correct. Correct me if I'm wrong.